# Understanding Wilson confidence interval for estimating precision of ML model

Tags: classification, estimators

Two related questions from statistics noob.

1. Can someone recommend a good statistics textbook that covers Wilson confidence interval? The reason why I'm looking for Wilson CI specifically is that I am a ML practitioner and recently I had to estimate CI for precision and recall of a certain ML model. My undergrad probability theory class didn't go that far, so a data scientist at my company told me to use Wilson confidence interval. I was embarrased that I haven't even heard that term, yet it appears that Wilson confidence interval is an industry standard, at least in my FAANG company. I checked a bunch of popular statistics textbooks and none of them talk about Wilson CI, or any other CI for population ratio, or how to measure CI of precision/recall. Do I need to look for more specific area within statistics to learn about that?
2. Is Wilson confidence interval  right or at least reasonable way to estimate CI for precision? After checking wikipedia article on it, I understand why it's good for recall, since the denominator for recall is the entire population of true positives, so I can see how evaluating model score on each sample is a Bernouuli trial. But it seems to me that it's not  applicable to precision in the same way, since denominator of precision is the set of all samples with model score greater than threshold, and so it varies with threshold. And we would have to consider Bernoulli trial to be looking at the label of each example, but this doesn't make sense to me since the label is actually known before we train and evaluate the model.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval Also see the book *Categorical Data Analysis* by Alan Agresti, chapter 1 (*et seq*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Wilson interval is one of the good options for a confidence interval for precision (which I would call positive predictive value).

It's true that the label is determined before you know the prediction when you're testing the model, but that doesn't matter. You can still ask "among those who scored above the threshold, what proportion are truly positive", and you still answer that question by finding everyone in the same who scores above the threshold and counting up the number who are actually positives and number who are actually negatives.  If someone gives you a bunch of records and says "these all scored above the threshold in the validation test; go look up their labels", you still learn an independent binary piece of information for each record when you look them up. And the total amount of information you learn depends on how many records are in the bunch (even if it's random).

Formally, if you have pairs of binary observations $(T_i, X_i)$ on $n$ individuals, where $P(T_i=1)$ depends on $X_i$, the distribution of $X_i$ *conditional on* $T_i=1$ is still Bernoulli, and the distribution of $\sum_i X_i$ conditional on $\sum_i T_i$ is still Binomial. In training you have already measured $X_i$ before you compute $T_i$. In production use you haven't measured $X_i$ when you compute $T_i$, and in validation it can go either way.  It doesn't matter for the math -- these are just correlational quantities, and direction in time isn't important.